# Escape ;(semicolon) in aspnet core connection string in appsettings.json file

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created a web application. I am trying to connect to MS Sql database through entity framework.

I have an issue in the below connection string in appsettings.json file.

In the connection string password contains semicolon as below.

> DefaultConnection": "Server=server name; Database=my db; User
>   Id=myuser; Password=HjkT;tk-k@=?55\; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;

while i am trying to access the entity framework getting this error

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'tk-k@'

I tried putting this password in double quotes/single quote/" . But still facing this error.

Comment: Can you change your password to not have a semi-colon in it?

Comment: @tadman Thats not in my hand, I asked to my client to change it. but here should be some solution.. right?

Comment: What about putting a backslash "\" before the semicolon?

Comment: @HasanIbrahim I tried that still same issue..

Comment: You need to set it as literal somehow. Hasan has an idea that could work. If you can find a reference for the format of this DSN maybe that's the key. I go out of my way to set passwords that work with these sorts of descriptors.

Comment: If escaping with "\" work you'd need to double escape it, like "\\;" or "\\\;". Or try using `{;}`

Comment: `Password='HjkT;tk-k@=?55\\'` works for me. You need to use both single quote and double escape

Answer (score 13):

That's not `appsettings.json` issue, it's connection string issue.

> The basic format of a connection string includes a series of
>   keyword/value pairs separated by semicolons. The equal sign (=)
>   connects each keyword and its value. To include values that contain a
>   semicolon, single-quote character, or double-quote character, the
>   value must be enclosed in double quotation marks
>   *[from here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx)*

So your connection string shoud look like:

> Server=server name; Database=my db; User Id=myuser; Password="HjkT;tk-k@=?55\"; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;

And as soon as quote and backslash are special symbols for json - you should escape them with backslash. Here is your file:

```
{
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=server name; Database=my db; User Id=myuser; Password=\"HjkT;tk-k@=?55\\\"; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
}
```

Comment: You can use single quotes when string starts with double-quotes.